# Cannot call to a service in my Security LIstener

Tags: grails

I am using a SecurityListener to listen to authentication events.

```
class ProductSecurityEventListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    def eventService;

    void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
         def user = event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
         def secUser = SecUser.findByUsername(user.username)
         eventService.logEventLogin(secUser);
}
```

I define my listener bean in resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    productSecurityEventListener(ProductSecurityEventListener);
}
```

I enable it in my config.groovy

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
```

I keep getting a null pointer on the eventservice.logEventLogin

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method logEventLogin() on null object
```

I debug and I can see events firing and the event method being invoked.  I just can't for the life of me figure out why eventService is not injected.

Here is my service

```
class EventService {
    def logEventLogin(SecUser secUser) {
        event event = new Event(eventType: EventEnum.LOGIN,  secUser: secUser, eventDate: new Date());
        event.save();
    }
```

Any ideas or tips welcomed?

Comment: where and how you're defining `ProductSecurityEventListener` bean?

Comment: as I see, you don't set `eventService`, so it have `null` value

Comment: @IgorArtamonov But how do I set it. I thought the framework did that for me because it is a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `eventService` property:

```
beans = {
    productSecurityEventListener(ProductSecurityEventListener) {
       eventService = ref('eventService')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Al an alternative to Igor's approach, you could enable autowiring for your bean, so any future dependencies you need to add (e.g. if you discover in future that you need `def grailsApplication`) will also be wired in automatically:

```
beans = {
    productSecurityEventListener(ProductSecurityEventListener) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = 'byName'
    }
}
```